# Wordpress .htaccess rewrite custom html pages

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've made static AMPhtml files which I want to connect later with WordPress.

My structure is:

/amp/index.html

/amp/subpages.html

I've tried for soooo long time now and it never works how I'd like it to work.

in .htaccess in root directory I have:

```html
# BEGIN Static AMP
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ / [R,L,NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ /$1 [R,L]
# END Static AMP

# BEGIN Security
<files wp-config.php>
    order allow,deny
    deny from all
</files>
Options -Indexes
<files ~ "^.*\.([Hh][Tt][Aa])">
    order allow,deny
    deny from all
    satisfy all
</files>
# END Security

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress

#-----------------------------------------------------------------#
# NOTE:                                                           #
# When testing your .htaccess do not use 301 redirects.           # 
# Use 302 until finished testing, as the browser will cache 301s. #
#-----------------------------------------------------------------#

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------#
# FLAGS:                                                                      #
# [R]  redirect, by default 302, can use [R=301]                              #
# [NC] flag causes the RewriteRule to be matched in a case-insensitive manner #
# [L]  flag causes mod_rewrite to stop processing the rule set.               #
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------#
```

What I'd like this to do is to Rewrite

http://www.example.com/amp/index.html
to 
http://www.example.com/amp/

and

http://www.example.com/amp/subpages.html
to
http://www.example.com/amp/subpages

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question.

```html
# BEGIN Static AMP
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteRule ^amp/index\.html$ /amp [R,L,NC]
  # example.com/page will display the contents of example.com/page.html
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
  RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1.html [L,QSA]
  # 301 from example.com/page.html to example.com/page
  RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /.*\.html\ HTTP/
  RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ /$1 [R=301]
  RewriteRule ^amp/index$ /amp [R=301,L]
 </IfModule>
# END Static AMP

# BEGIN Security
<files wp-config.php>
    order allow,deny
    deny from all
</files>
Options -Indexes
<files ~ "^.*\.([Hh][Tt][Aa])">
    order allow,deny
    deny from all
    satisfy all
</files>
# END Security

# BEGIN WordPress
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
 </IfModule>
# END WordPress

#-----------------------------------------------------------------#
# NOTE:                                                           #
# When testing your .htaccess do not use 301 redirects.           # 
# Use 302 until finished testing, as the browser will cache 301s. #
#-----------------------------------------------------------------#

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------#
# FLAGS:                                                                      #
# [R]  redirect, by default 302, can use [R=301]                              #
# [NC] flag causes the RewriteRule to be matched in a case-insensitive manner #
# [L]  flag causes mod_rewrite to stop processing the rule set.               #
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------#

#-------------------------------------------------------#
# This checks for existing folders (-d) and files (-f): #
# RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d                   #
# RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f                   #
#-------------------------------------------------------#

#-------------------------#
# .HTACCESS Testing Tool  #
# http://htaccess.mwl.be/ #
#-------------------------#
```